# How to delete directories contents (and not the directory itself) using find -exec and rm?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to delete the content of some directories (but not the directory itself) using this:

```
find -type d -name someDirs -exec rm -rf {}/* \;
```

But it doesn't work. Any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your command is that wildcard expansion is done by your shell before the command is actually called. As your shell does not find a file that matches `{}/*` (as you don't have a directory with a literal name `{}` in the current directory), the `*` is passed to the command unchanged, which will then be modified by `find` to delete files named literal `*` in your `someDirs` directories, as the `rm` command will not expand wildcards (again). You can "debug" this by running

```
find -type d -name someDirs -exec echo rm -rf {}/* \;
```

instead. To make sure that the shell has a chance to expand your `*`, let `exec` spawn another shell which can expand the `*` (and protect the command from being expanded first with single quotes) like this:

```
find -type d -name someDirs -exec sh -c 'rm -rf {}/*' \;
```

or test it like this:

```
find -type d -name someDirs -exec sh -c 'echo rm -rf {}/*' \;
```

Answer (score 9):

You can give the directory (or directories) as arguments to [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and tell it to *skip* it with the `-mindepth` option:

> -mindepth levels
>        Do not apply any tests or actions at levels less than levels (a non-negative integer).
>        **-mindepth 1 means process all files except the command line arguments.**

So, your command would be:

```
find SomeDir1 SomeDir2 -mindepth 1 -exec rm -rf '{}' \+
```

Answer (score 7):

```
  find . -type f -delete
```

will delete all files in and below the current directory, leaving the directory structure alone.

If your find command doesn't support -delete (it's slightly modern, but been there fore a few years now), then:

```
  find . -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Edit: As noted by Nate, this is not the right answer.

Comment: It looks to me like the OP wants to delete not only the files but also the directories under `someDirs`, just not `someDirs` itself.  So we don't actually want to leave the directory structure alone.  I left a comment requesting clarification.

Comment: If so, cd somdDirs && rm -r * will do the trick but is extremely scary to post :)

Comment: As I read it, there may be many directories named `someDirs`, possibly at different depths below the current directory.

Comment: Ahhh, I see.  Good point.

Comment: Maybe something with -regex or -path, but I don't feel comfortable recommending anything (the risk is... high :))